# .NET application cannot find registry key using wine and mono

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mono, wine

I will start with my system.

Raspberry pi 3 B+, raspbian jessie, running Debian wheezy on a x86 chroot environment, and with wine installed, don't ask about how I did this, is pretty easy however is just really slow. (I don't care for what I want it) (Hey, I'm sure wine works, I already ran multiple commom apps like notepad and winword, also winecfg and other commands works pretty well)

My problem is the following, I got a windows .exe that requires .NET 4.0 to run, however, mono seems to me to be the best candidate to do it so I installed it on a new wine prefix, set the bin folder to the PATH variable, and ran a "mono --version" command on wine cmd, everything looks fine, this is my wine cmd output:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.1 (Visual Studio built mono)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       normal
    Notification:  Thread + polling
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

Now, when I try to run the .NET app it immediately says the following:

```
please set registry key HKLM\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\InstallRoot to point to the .NET Framework install location
```

Obviously this location doesn't exist as I haven't install .NET, so the real question is, if I want to set that registry key to work with mono instead, to which folder of my Mono installation should I point it?

Comment: No one?, I did a wine-mono installation, but executing the program give me a lot of errors, I think mono on windows is working better

Comment: Nobody would trouble himself/herself to use Wine+Mono, an almost abandoned way. .NET Core is way better and fully supported by Microsoft (release 2.1 is in preview right now with ARM support).